# How to merge multiple json arrays into one array swift sub array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, merge

I have two json arrays :

```
     1) 
    [
      {
       "userId": 9
      },
      {
       "userId": 14
      }
     ]

     2) 
     [{"role": "1", "group": "3"}, {"role": "1", "group": "2"}]
```

I would like to merge two arrays like as follows  : 
Is it possible to have the solution by javascript?

```
    [
     {"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"2"},
     {"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"2"}
     {"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"3"},
     {"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"3"}
    ]
```

I tried to use Let however I couldn't find the way to manipulate switch the subarray :

```
     let arr1 = 
     [{ "userId": 9 }, { "userId": 14 }]
     let arr2 = [{"role": "1","group": "3"}, {"role": "1","group": "2" }] 

     let result = arr1.map(o => Object.assign(o, ...arr2));

     console.log(result);
    return result;
```

The result is like this :

```
    [{"userId":9,"role":"1","group":"2"},{"userId":14,"role":"1","group":"2"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service.  What have you tried please?  What went wrong?

Comment: You're on the right track.  But you need to `map` that process over the elements of `x` and not simply apply them to it.  See the answer from Mohammad Usman for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map()` with `Object.assign()`:

```js
let arr1 = [{"userId": 9}, {"userId": 14}],
    arr2 = [{"rid": 1}, {"mid": 201}];
     
let result = arr1.map(o => Object.assign(o, ...arr2));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I edit the question with array. would you take a look how it works?

Answer (score 0):

@Mohammad Usman has a better answer but one simpler to understand is to create a new object with the desired values and push it into the resulting array. Something as follows:

```
users = [
    {"userId": 9},
    {"userId": 14}
];

data = [
    {"rid": 1},
    {"mid": 201}
];
result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    result.push({
        "rid": data[0].rid,
        "mid": data[1].mid,
        "userId": users[i].userId
    });
}
```

Here `result` will have the desired output.